# fatal: bad config line 1 in file .git/config

Tags: git, visual-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code

fatal: bad config line 1 in file .git/config

In trying to run flutter i am getting this error.
I tried flutter upgrade --force, flutter channel stable as well as reinstalling flutter
but none of these commands fix the error

Comment: What's the first line of `.git/config`?

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue by deleting the config file under flutter/.git/config and then running

> git init

command in the flutter directory. Then ran flutter doctor and all is good.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$FLUTTER_INSTALL_DIR/.git/config` should look something like this:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "stable"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/stable
[branch "beta"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/beta
[branch "dev"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/dev
```

Please note that this is **not** one of your git repos.  If it doesn't look like this, reinstall flutter.

Comment: $FLUTTER_INSTALL_DIR/.git/config 
Should I run this in the terminal?

Comment: No, that's a file for you to examine, according to the instructions above.

Comment: I tried reinstalling flutter and my config file looks like this:

[core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = false
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 symlinks = false
 ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
 url = https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "stable"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/stable


and I still getting the same error